# spark test fail with maven but success with Intellij due to winutils

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark, intellij-idea, junit

When I using the maven panel in Intellij to launch all the test, I get some spark test falling with this a basic wintutils related problem :

terminated with exception: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z

[image]

if I launch the whole class or the failled test with Intellij, the test pass:

[image]

but if I launch the selected class with maven it pass too:

[image]

My goal was to test a listener implementation:

```
@Test
public void simpleStreamingListenerMemoryStreaming() {
    SparkContext sc = new SparkContext("local[1]", "test");
    SparkSession ss = new SparkSession(sc);
    StreamingListenerImpl listener = new StreamingListenerImpl(jobConfig);
    ss.streams().addListener(listener);
    ss.sparkContext().env().metricsSystem().registerSource(listener);

    StructField[] kafkaStructFields1 = new StructField[]{
            new StructField("key", DataTypes.StringType, true, Metadata.empty()),
            new StructField("value", DataTypes.StringType, true, Metadata.empty()),
    };

    StructType kafkaStreamSchema = new StructType(kafkaStructFields1);

    MemoryStream<Row> input = new MemoryStream<>(1, ss.sqlContext(), RowEncoder.apply(kafkaStreamSchema));
    Dataset<Row> inputDS = input.toDS();

    StreamingQuery streamingQuery = inputDS
            .writeStream()
            .format("console")
            .queryName("testMemoryStream")
            .outputMode("append")
            .start();

    List<Row> values = new ArrayList<>();
    values.add(RowFactory.create("key1", "value1"));

    input.addData(JavaConverters.asScalaIteratorConverter(values.iterator()).asScala().toSeq());

    streamingQuery.processAllAvailable();
    streamingQuery.stop();

}
```

Even without creating a new SparkSession i get this problem.

Comment: Check if you have set correct SDK in intellij.
File>Project Structure>Project>SDK

Comment: I used the right SDK, i have more than 200 tests, also some including spark that all pass, except for 2